# Flex 4.5 mobile - view generation taking too long

Tags: apache-flex, mobile

I am creating an iPhone/iPad app using flex 4.5. I am pushing a view(consists of around 10 text inputs) to my view navigator and its taking too long. I tried using property `destructionPolicy="never"` but that is not going to help as it only works when popping to previous views and not `pushView()`.

This is what my view looks like:

```
<s:View xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009">
    <s:Scroller id="scroller" width="100%" height="100%" horizontalScrollPolicy="off">
             <s:HGroup id="idHgroup" width="100%">
        <s:Form id="idForm" >
            <s:FormItem label="label 1">
                                <s:TextInput id="amount" />
                            </s:FormItem>
                            <s:FormItem /> * 10
                     </s:Form>
        </s:HGroup>
</s:Scroller>
</s:View>
```

Any ideas how I can optimize this view?

Comment: Can you quantify too long?  Are you testing on an emulator or a device?  If a device, which one?  Are you using the 4.5.1 SDK?  According to docs; the Spark Form is not supported on a mobile device; have you created a mobile skin for it?  In 4.5.1 the iOS emulator uses AIR 2.6 while the ipa builds use AIR 2.7.  You should see better performance on the device than in the emulator.

Comment: Can you show more of your application code?  This particular segment of code shouldn't be the problem, I'm guessing it's something else.

Comment: Hi Flextras, on emulator it runs ok but on iphone 3gs and ipad 1 its slow (4-5 seconds).  I am using flex 4.5.1. I have not created a mobile skin. Can you point me to the resource that says spark form is not supported and about mobile skin? Thanks

Comment: Hi J_A_X, this is all my view contains. Its called by another view like: `code`<s:Button label="btn_form" width="80%" click="navigator.pushView(MyView, null, null)" />`code`

Comment: hi,have you find the answer for this? is it the FormItem? i'm facing the same issue also.